# Properties of Sobolev spaces $W^{k,p}(\Omega, E)$ where $E$ is a Banach space

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$Let $E$ be a Banach space with norm $\|\cdot\|_E$ and let $\Omega\subset \R^n$ be an open set.

For $k\geq 0, p\geq 1$ we define   $W^{k,p}(\Omega, E)$, the Sobolev space of maps from $\R^n\to E$, as the closure of $C^\infty(\Omega, E)$ with respect to  the norm

$$\|f\|_{p,k} = \left(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}\int_{\R^n} \left\|\frac{\partial^\alpha}{\partial x^\alpha}f(x)\right\|_E^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}$$
$\alpha$ multiindex.

> Q0: References

> Q1: Do we still have Sobolev embedding theorems in this setting? I.e. if  and $k=p/n + r+\alpha$, $r\in \mathbb N, \alpha\in (0,1)$, then $$ W^{k,p}(\Omega, E) \subset C^{r,\alpha}(\Omega,E)$$ (Holder space on the RHS)?

> Q2: do we still have Rellich theorem, provided that $\Omega$ is bounded?

> Q3: Suppose now that $E = (H, \langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ is an Hilbert space. We have then a notion of distributional derivative for maps $f: \Omega\to H$, by saying that $D^\alpha f$ must satisfy
> $$\int_\Omega \langle D^\alpha  f(x), \varphi(x) \rangle_H \, dx = (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_\Omega \langle   f(x), D^\alpha\varphi(x) \rangle_H \, dx $$
> for all test functions $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega, H)$. Is it true in this case that $W^{k,p}(\Omega, H)$ is equal to the set of functions with  $k$ (distributional) derivatives in $L^2(\Omega, H)$?

Comment: Q0: A relevant reference is [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06161). Q2: You mean compactness of the embedding? No, just consider the subspace of constant functions with values in $E$.

Comment: If the visual difference between $||f||$ and $\|f\|$ is too subtle, consider that between $||f|| ||g||,$ coded as `||f|| ||g||`, and $\|f\|\|g\|,$ coded as `\|f\|\|g\|`. That is why the latter is standard usage and is the reason for one part of my edit to this question.